# About Python ThreadPool Question how can I solve?

Tags: python

Class For ThreadPool

```
import concurrent.futures
import importlib
import queue
import itertools
import threading
import time


class ThreadPool():
    def __init__(self, thread):
        self.max_thread = thread
        self.thread_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.max_thread)
        self.task_queue = queue.Queue()  # 使用线程安全的队列
        self.futures = {}
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    '''  
        module:字符串,模块名称  
        function:字符串,函数名  
        usernamelist:用户名列表  
        passwordlist:密码列表  
    '''

    def add_port_brute_task(self, module, function, host, port, usernamelist, passwordlist):
        combinations = list(itertools.product(usernamelist, passwordlist))
        for combination in combinations:
            username, password = combination
            new_task = (module, function, host, port, username, password)
            self.task_queue.put(new_task)  # 将任务添加到线程安全的队列中

    def start_port_brute_threadpool(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        while not self.task_queue.empty():  # 检查队列是否为空，而不是检查队列的大小是否为0
            module, function, host, port, username, password = self.task_queue.get()
            args = (host, port, username, password)
            future = self.thread_pool.submit(self.run_poc, module, function, args)
            self.futures[future] = (function, args)
        self.thread_pool.shutdown(wait=True)
        print("\n用时:%.2f 秒" % (time.time() - start_time))

    '''  
    通过importlib获取到模块,获取函数直接执行  
    '''

    def run_poc(self, module, func, args):
        module = importlib.import_module(module)
        function = getattr(module, func)
        result = function(*args)
        if result == True:
            self.thread_pool.shutdown(wait=False)
```

test.py:

```
from threads import ThreadPool
import multiprocessing
import rdp_brute
import time
def rdp_connect(host, port, username, passowrd):
    try:
        result=rdp_brute.check_rdp(host, port, username, passowrd, host)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print("[-]RDP连接出现异常", end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    usernamelist=[]
    passwordlist=[]
    passwordFile = open(r'top500.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for password in passwordFile:
        password = password.strip('\n')
        passwordlist.append(password)
    usernamelist.append('25018')
    host='192.168.23.128'
    port=3389

    pool = ThreadPool(10)
    function = 'rdp_connect'
    pool.add_port_brute_task('test', function, host, port, usernamelist, passwordlist)
    pool.start_port_brute_threadpool()
```

When I ran test.py, it encountered a situation where a password was repeatedly used for function execution multiple times?How can I correct my ThreadPool class to avoid this situation from happening?
[image]

How can I correct my ThreadPool class to avoid this situation from happening?

Comment: Hello! You should edit your question to write an additional information.

Comment: but you also get different output (other password, etc) or only 1 type?

Comment: I think the `while` is quite dangerous in general and I would suggest a `map`, you also never check if the futures finished their job

Comment: The way itertoos.product() works, is that it first pairs all usernames with the first password, then all usernames with the second password and so on (or the other way around, depending on argument order). So it's no surprise that you get the same one multiple times. See documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product